# Error in computing the triple integral symbolically

Tags: matlab

I am trying to evaluate a triple integration in Matlab, by the use of symbolic representation. Following is my code:

```
fun = @(x,y,z) (((2*pi)^length(data))*sqrt(det(COVAR)))^-1*exp(-0.5*([x y z]-OMEGA)'*inv(COVAR)*([x y z]-OMEGA));

q = integral3(fun,-Inf,Inf,-Inf,Inf,-Inf,Inf)
```

The above function is a multivariate gaussian with a 3x3 covariance matrix  (COVAR) and a 10000x3 samples, (data) should ideally result in 1.0 as its answer.

But it results in error messages...
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in @(x,y,z)exp(-0.5*([x,y,z]-OMEGA)'*inv(COVAR)*([x,y,z]-OMEGA))

Error in integral3>@(y,z)FUN(x(1)*ones(size(z)),y,z) (line 138)
            @(y,z)FUN(x(1)*ones(size(z)),y,z), ...

Error in integral2Calc>@(y)fun(xi*ones(size(y)),y) (line 18)
    @(y)fun(xi*ones(size(y)),y),y1i,y2i,opstruct.integralOptions), ...

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
                fx = FUN(t);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 103)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@minusInfToInfInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral2Calc>@(xi,y1i,y2i)integralCalc(@(y)fun(xi*ones(size(y)),y),y1i,y2i,opstruct.integralOptions)

Error in integral2Calc>@(x)arrayfun(@(xi,y1i,y2i)integralCalc(@(y)fun(xi*ones(size(y)),y),y1i,y2i,opstruct.integralOptions),x,ymin(x),ymax(x))
(line 17)
innerintegral = @(x)arrayfun(@(xi,y1i,y2i)integralCalc( ...

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
                fx = FUN(t);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 103)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@minusInfToInfInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral2Calc>integral2i (line 20)
[q,errbnd] = integralCalc(innerintegral,xmin,xmax,opstruct.integralOptions);

Error in integral2Calc (line 7)
    [q,errbnd] = integral2i(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,optionstruct);

Error in integral3/innerintegral (line 137)
        Q1 = integral2Calc( ...

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
                fx = FUN(t);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 103)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@minusInfToInfInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral3 (line 121)
    Q = integralCalc(@innerintegral,xmin,xmax,integralOptions);

I do not quite understand the error messages and any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Actually, I would like to compute the value of the function in the first quadrant only....

```
q = integral3(fun,0,Inf,0,Inf,0,Inf) %%something like this.
```

The idea behind this exercise is to compute the normalizing constant for the above multivariate distribution if we happen to restrict ourselves to the positive parameters/ estimate values only.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming COVAR is a 3x3... you have a 1x3*3x3 in:

```
([x y z]-OMEGA)'*inv(COVAR)
```

This results in a 1x3. Then, you try to multiply by another 1x3:

```
*([x y z]-OMEGA)
```

So the inner dimensions are 3 and 1 (don't agree).

Comment: Dear Mike C. I appreciate your answer. Thanks for pointing out the trivial mistake. But I am not done with the original problem. Could you look into the error message?  It appears to me that integral3 could not handle the 'array-valued options'.

Comment: Did you try integral3(fun, -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf, 'ArrayValued', 'true')?

Comment: I tried integral3, but it seems that it does not have a provision for arrayed inputs. After trying nested int 3 times for the multivariate gaussian and limits [-Inf, Inf] for all the variables I am able to recover the required result ie. 1.0. But when the limits are [0, Inf] for all the 3 variables the code takes a very long time...

Comment: I have posted my issue as a new answer....please have a look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the I am entering the sequence correctly, but I get a different error. It appears to me that integral3 could not handle the 'array-valued options'.

```
fun = @(x,y,z) (((2*pi)^length(data))*sqrt(det(COVAR)))^-1*exp(-0.5*[x-OMEGA(1);y-OMEGA(2);z-OMEGA(3)]'*inv(COVAR)*[x-OMEGA(1);y-OMEGA(2);z-OMEGA(3)])

q = integral3(fun,-Inf,Inf,-Inf,Inf,-Inf,Inf)
```

Error using integralCalc/finalInputChecks (line 515)
Output of the function must be the same size as the input. If FUN is an array-valued integrand, set the 'ArrayValued' option to true.

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 315)
                finalInputChecks(x,fx);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 103)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@minusInfToInfInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral2Calc>@(xi,y1i,y2i)integralCalc(@(y)fun(xi*ones(size(y)),y),y1i,y2i,opstruct.integralOptions)

Error in integral2Calc>@(x)arrayfun(@(xi,y1i,y2i)integralCalc(@(y)fun(xi*ones(size(y)),y),y1i,y2i,opstruct.integralOptions),x,ymin(x),ymax(x))
(line 17)
innerintegral = @(x)arrayfun(@(xi,y1i,y2i)integralCalc( ...

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
                fx = FUN(t);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 103)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@minusInfToInfInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral2Calc>integral2i (line 20)
[q,errbnd] = integralCalc(innerintegral,xmin,xmax,opstruct.integralOptions);

Error in integral2Calc (line 7)
    [q,errbnd] = integral2i(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,optionstruct);

Error in integral3/innerintegral (line 137)
        Q1 = integral2Calc( ...

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
                fx = FUN(t);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 103)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@minusInfToInfInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral3 (line 121)
    Q = integralCalc(@innerintegral,xmin,xmax,integralOptions);